# Is it possible to create a SQL Server UDF with Delphi for win32?

Tags: sql-server, delphi, sql-server-2008, user-defined-functions

I store files in blobs (using SQl Server filestream).

I stored them zipping them (with [Zipforge](http://www.componentace.com/zip_component_zip_delphi_zipforge.htm) Delphi component).

I'd need to allow some users retrieveing the files with a simple query and obtaining them already unzipped.

So I would like to have a UDF called RetrieveFile with a single ID as parameter. This function returns a BLOB that is a not zipped file.

Is it possible to do this in Delphi or I must use .NET?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need CLR stored procedure to do this and in pure Delphi is impossible to create the assembly. However you can use Delphi Prism to develop it. Check out [this article](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2011/01/13/microsoft-sql-server-clr-and-delphi-prism-part-1-clr-stored-procedures/) written by RRUZ.

Comment: Hmm... An extended stored procedure can't do that?

Comment: about Delphi Prism: why should I buy Delphi Prism when I can use for free the visual studio Express version of c#? It is really true that in the Delphi world we are ready to pay for everything while in the other "worlds" they are free or at least also free.

Comment: @user193655 - in that case use .NET; you've been asking how to do it in Delphi :)